# Python normalization without any packages

Tags: python

Trying to calculate L1 Norm without using any packages in python

Lets say i have vector: `l = [2.34, 3.32, 6.32, 2.5, 3,3, 5.32]`

And I want to find L1 of this vector without any packages:

I have calculated the

```
mean = sum(l) / float(len(l)
variance = sum(pow(x-mean, 3) for x in l) / len(l)
normalized = [(x-mean)/std for x in l]
```

How do I get the L1-Norm

Comment: If you don't want to use any packages, why did you tag `numpy`?

Comment: Quick note: the variance is the sum of the **squares** of the distance from the mean. Not the cubes. Also, your code as-posted would not run. Finally, please post your desired output and what you've tried so far. Also, are you looking for the L1 norm from the mean? The median? From 0?

Comment: what is `L1` and is that `std` or `variance`? please take more care with your code snippets

Comment: I do not really understand why you seem to be capable of calculating something that is close to (but not entirely) a 2-norm, but fail to calculate an 1-norm?

Comment: Why do you not want any packages? Packages are good. They are why we can be productive in python in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the L1 norm like this:

```
sum(map(abs, l))
# 25.8
```

To check (using Numpy):

```
import numpy as np
np.linalg.norm(l, 1)
# 25.800000000000001
```

Comment: Thats not the L1-Norm

Comment: The `linalg.norm` is defined as the vector L1 norm - like [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/vector-norms-machine-learning/).  @RafaelC, you're right, I was doing L2.

Comment: make it `sum(map(abs,l))` for faster execution

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in `math`module, the $L^1$ norm would be:

```
L1 = sum([math.fabs(x) for x in l])
```

Comment: better: `L1 = sum(map(math.fabs,l))`